# CSS Hyperbola Shape

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I've seen all kinds of shapes from tvs to eggs to simple triangles. But how would one make a hyperbolic shape, **filled in** similar to this nuclear tower shape?

[image]

Comment: Please Post the code that you have tried..

Comment: Some thing you need to put . Or first try urself then come up with an issue ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a `border-radius` with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLLE/)

Here am using a wrapper element with a `class` - `.wrap` and than am nesting a child element with a `class` - `.object`, now I will break up the selectors explanation for you, first, am assigning `position: relative;` for the parent element so that the `absolute` positioned child elements don't fly out in the wild.. second is I am using an element with `overflow: hidden;` which is important so that the rounded `pseudo elements` are hidden..

And at last, I use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and `position` them using `absolute`, and than we have to set it correctly using `top`, `left`, `right` properties respectively.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="object"></div>
</div>

.wrap {
     position:relative;
}

.object {
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 180px;
    height: 215px;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.object:before, 
.object:after {
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -53px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 300px;
}

.object:before {
    left: -263px;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.object:after {
    right: -263px;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```